# POST request with a json body containing a nested object

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, rest

I would like my Rest API to receive a json containing a nested object,
and to save that item in a MySQL database. I'm using Spring.

The object to save is an Alert which contains a Localisation. They are both stored in their own table, with a One-to-One relationship.

The problem I get is an HTTP 400 error (bad request), sent by tomcat.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an example of a json to send:

```
{
   "date" : "29.07.2018",
   "localisation" : {
       "latitude" : "value",
       "longitude" : "value"
   } 
}
```

Here is the controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = URL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void sendAlert(@RequestBody Alert alert) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(alert);
}
```

And the classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alerts", schema = "schema")
public class Alert {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String date;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_localisation")
    private Localisation localisation;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "localisations", schema = "schema")
public class Localisation {
    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String latitude;

    @Column
    private String longitude;
}
```

Comment: check the data being sent in developer console in your web browser, Bad request error comes when your required object is missing.

Comment: can you add this property on top of `Alert` and `Localisation` class `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown= true)`

Comment: share the client code that gets the error. Also on the server side, you can see some stacktrace, share that as well